# Do you know if you have zerovalent iron nanoparticles in liquid how to measure minimal magnetic force required for separation of these nanoparticles?

Tags: magnetic-fields, absorption, magnetostatics

I think of measuring mag susceptibility from VSM data (magnetization divided by the applied field) but I am not sure if this would be enough. Maybe if I employ SQUID measurements, but in that case I wouldnt know how to prepare a sample. Do you know any paper or protocol for this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to measure, but could you use [magnetic tweezers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_tweezers)?